# Will a 45 degree elbow resolve a sink drain being to close to the drain stub?

Tags: plumbing

I'm replacing a vanity and after installing the P Trap, I found the junction of the pipe going to the stubout was leaking.  The ferrule was hitting right on the bit of plastic on the outside of the pipe, like a stamped brand or something.  I thought this was an aberration but I see this bit of plastic on the outside near the elbow in images from other plumbing jobs, so I assume the nut and ferrule are just too close to the junction and need to be further along on the straight portion?

Assuming that, then the stubout is simply too close, so I was going to add a 45 degree elbow to make room for everything to fit.  But now I'm struggling to find a 1 1/4" 45 degree elbow.  My local Ace, Home Depot, and Amazon all have 1 1/4" P traps and parts and a 1 1/2" elbow, but not a 1 1/4" 45 degree elbow.  Why not?  What is going on?  I must be missing something.

[image: This is where it is leaking]

[image: See where the ferrule is hitting that jutting dot of plastic]

Comment: Where a P trap is too close to a wall stubout sometimes a bottle trap is the cure.  That may not be the problem so pictures would be great.

Comment: Thanks, I added some pictures.

Comment: My guess is that's some sort of "maximum insertion" mark and it is functioning exactly as designed. It's probably to keep you from inserting the pipe so far in that you're starting to get into the bend and won't get a good seal from the gasket and the nut. Not 100% certain this is the case, and no suggestions on a fix at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by shaving that nub off with a razor knife. If you can then tighten it and get a seal, all good. It's just an injection-molding port stub.

If that doesn't hold water, I'd look at adding a 45 ell to the stubout, either by threading fittings on or by cutting off the threaded fitting and cementing on an ell and a new threaded end. You don't want extra turns in your small pipe.

Comment: Just getting back to this.  I was able to shave and sand it smooth and then all was well.